# How to Use Backticks in Hibernate Criteria API for MySQL Reserved Keywords?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to use Hibernate Criteria API to generate a query for a table named `Lead` in MySQL8, which is a reserved keyword. However, when I use the Criteria API, Hibernate generates a query without backticks around the table name, causing a syntax error in MySQL.

I want to generate a query like this:

```sql
select * from `Lead` lead0_ where lead0_.isClosed=0 
order by lead0_.updatedAt desc limit 20
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Lead> query = cb.createQuery(Lead.class);
Root<Lead> root = query.from(Lead.class);

Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[1];
predicates[0] = cb.equal(root.get("isClosed"), false);
query.where(predicates);

query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get("updatedAt")));

List<Lead> leads = entityManager.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(20).getResultList();
```

However, Hibernate generates a query without backticks around the table name:

```sql
select * from Lead lead0_ where lead0_.isClosed=0 
order by lead0_.updatedAt desc limit 20
```

How can I modify my Hibernate Criteria API code to include backticks around the `Lead` table name to avoid this syntax error in MySQL?

I tried these approaches but they did not work:

```java
@Table(name = "\"Lead\"")
public class Lead {
}
```

and:

```java
@Table(name = "`Lead`")
public class Lead {
}
```

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem using your code. Both of your attempted solutions work for me.

Comment: Another approach (which also works for me) is to use `<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>` in your `persistence.xml` file. But (a) that applies to all SQL (may be overkill); and (b) you shouldn't need it, anyway, given both your attempts should already have worked.